# how to react in typescript fetch data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state, tsx

I am currently using `typescript` of `React`.
I want to use `map` using `fetch`.
How to define the type fetchdata in map
Can I ask for your advice?

```
interface Root {
  requests: Request[];
}

interface Request {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  client: string;
  due: string;
  count?: number;
  amount: number;
  method: string[];
  material: string[];
  status: string;
  docs?: number;
}


const Board = () => {
  const [cardInfo, setCardInfo] = useState<Root[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/requests')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => setCardInfo(res));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <S.CardWrap>
        {cardInfo.map((Request): Request => {
          return <Card cardInfo={Request} />;
        })}
      </S.CardWrap>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I don't know why people vote down these questions; this is a straightforward question with a simple response. Please do not ruin the community.

Answer (score 0):

Just do your type annotation inside your parenthesis, like

```
cardInfo.map((request: Request) => { ... })
```

Instead of outside